# Stopping a line break in list

Tags: spacing, lists

I am writing a memo style document for my job that has to be formatted in a very specific manner, often without regard to good typesetting practices.  I am relatively new to Latex, so I am having some trouble.  I want to get this:

Refs: (a) an reference that may be a couple lines long
      (b) this should be on a new line, with (b) lined up with (a).

Here is what I have so far:

```
  Refs: 
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item (a reference to something)
 \nolinebreak 
 \item (another reference)
 \end{enumerate}
```

But when I compile it as a PDF it comes out like this:

Refs:

(a) blah blah blah

(b) blah blah

So, in summary, I want the first reference to start on the same line as Refs:, I want the references to be aligned to each other, and I dont wat it to skip a line.  Like I said, I am pretty new at this, but I couldnt find anything relating to this with a google search.  I would appreciate any help.  I am using the latest version of Texmaker on an Ubuntu machine, and compiling with pdflatex.

EDIT:

To be clear, after adding the [inline] option, here is what I have now.

```
Refs:
\begin{enumerate*}[label = (\alph*)]
\item Lucas, G., \& Rubel, R. (Eds.). (2011). Ethics and the Military  
Profession:the Moral Foundations of Leadership (NROTC Third.). 
Boston, \\ 
\item Schenck v. United States, 249 U.S. 47 (1919)
\end{enumerate*}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

what I want is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question in the first place. Here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newlength{\auxlength}
\newenvironment{references}
{\settowidth{\auxlength}{Refs:}%
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=\auxlength,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=0pt]
        \item[\normalfont Refs:]%
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=2em,labelsep=.5em]}
        {\end{enumerate}\end{description}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{references}
    \item (a reference to something)
    \item (another reference)
\end{references}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This is getting me in the right direction I think, but the second reference is left aligning (when I add \\ after the first reference), rather than lining up under (A).

Comment: @christopherbrown0317 Why are you linebreaking now? If you want to have everything indented, you should wrap all of this in a description.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean, like I said, I am pretty new to this.  I did a line break so that the second item would appear on a new line instead of inline with the first item.  I still want the first item on the same line as Ref:, but the second item needs to be lined up with the first.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I am new to the forum, do I need to mark the thread as answered?  Thank you again!